# SQL Query String to be fetched as column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my table data
table name-->mytable

```
id     string
1      A01,B01,C01
2      A02,B02,C02
3      A01,B01
4      C01,C02
5      C02,C03
```

i need output like below, anyone help here to write oracle SQL.

```
id |   A01 |  B01 | A02 | B02 | C01 | C02 | C03 |
1  |    Y  |  Y   |     |     |  Y  |     |     |
2  |       |      | Y   | Y   |     | Y   |     |
3  |    Y  |  Y   |     |     |     |     |     |        
4  |       |      |     |     |  Y  | Y   |     |
5  |       |      |     |     |     | Y   |  Y  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below (not exactly but somewhere) dynamic query to generate the same output -

```
select ID, TRANSLATE(A01, 10, 'Y ') A01, TRANSLATE(B01, 10, 'Y ') B01,
       TRANSLATE(A02, 10, 'Y ') A02, TRANSLATE(B02, 10, 'Y ') B02,
       TRANSLATE(C01, 10, 'Y ') C01, TRANSLATE(C02, 10, 'Y ') C02,
       TRANSLATE(C03, 10, 'Y ') C03
from(select id, value
       from (select distinct id, trim(regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, level)) value
               from t
            connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
           order by id) t2)
pivot (COUNT(*) for value in ('A01' A01, 'B01' B01, 'A02' A02, 'B02' B02, 'C01' C01,
                              'C02' C02, 'C03' C03))
order by id;
```

You can pass your column list in the pivot clause and can select the same column as well.

Here is the [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0843d7e00ac0e778d608e0ef9a6f7a4d).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` expressions:

```
select id,
       (case when string like '%A01%' then 'Y' end) as a01,
       (case when string like '%B01%' then 'Y' end) as b01,
       . . .
from t;
```

Note:  Because all your codes are three characters, you don't have to worry about conflicts (such as `'A01'` matching `'BA01'`.  That somewhat simplifies the logic.

Comment: thanks for your input here string contains some times 70 values comma separated then we need to write 70 case statement that is not valid right

Comment: @BasavarajNavalagi But how are you going to decide how many columns should be there? What is the criteria for that?

Comment: max 80 columns will be there and string can change any time like instead of A01,B01
they put A1,B1 THEN We need to generate A1 and B1 column